# Working with new lines in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, newline

The code below gets text from textbox,splits by ",", then if words count more than 10 sends it to php via ajax. I designed this code to work with barcode reader (setinterval... etc). Now the problem is, can't set barcode reader to leave comma after each scanned barcode. It adds line break.

So lets say  ids.val(); is line break seperated words. How do I convert them into comma seperated words?

Comment: Can you please point to the **relevant** code?

Comment: Have you tried to add a `split("\n")` to split it by new lines first?

Comment: @gdoron Updated question. Check out

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.indexOf("\n")
```

and

```
.split("\n")
```

instead of the comma-versions! Note that you might want to vary with `\n` and `\r\n` as some browsers implement a newline character as the former and some as the latter.

If you would want to convert all newlines to comma's, then use

```
commaSeparatedString = newlineSeparatedString.replace(/\\n/g, ",");
```

Comment: It's always better to *not* update your question if that renders initial answers useless, but still I added the answer to your new question.